# Merge: ‘NA’, ‘NA’ are duplicated in the result

Tags: r

I am looking at the sample code from this link.

http://www.milanor.net/blog/maps-in-r-plotting-data-points-on-a-map/

It seems like the data set locations have changes, so I changed my code, just slightly, to accommodate.

```
airports <- read.delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat", sep=",")
colnames(airports) <- c("ID", "name", "city", "country", "IATA_FAA", "ICAO", "lat", "lon", "altitude", "timezone", "DST")
head(airports)

library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-20, 59), ylim = c(35, 71), asp = 1)
points(airports$lon, airports$lat, col = "red", cex = .6)



routes <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat", header=F)
colnames(routes) <- c("airline", "airlineID", "sourceAirport", "sourceAirportID", "destinationAirport", "destinationAirportID", "codeshare", "stops", "equipment")
head(routes)

library(plyr)
departures <- ddply(routes, .(sourceAirportID), "nrow")
names(departures)[2] <- "flights"
arrivals <- ddply(routes, .(destinationAirportID), "nrow")
names(arrivals)[2] <- "flights"
```

All of this seems fine.  The code below seems to be off, but I'm not sure why.

```
airportD <- merge(airports, departures, by.x = "ID", by.y = "sourceAirportID")
airportA <- merge(airports, arrivals, by.x = "ID", by.y = "destinationAirportID")
```

I'm getting this error:

> Warning message: 
>   In merge.data.frame(airports, departures, by.x =
>   "ID", by.y = "sourceAirportID") :   column names ‘NA’, ‘NA’ are
>   duplicated in the result
>
> Warning message: 
>   In merge.data.frame(airports, arrivals, by.x = "ID", by.y =
>   "destinationAirportID") :   column names ‘NA’, ‘NA’ are duplicated in
>   the result

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, those are only warnings, not errors. That is, everything still works, but perhaps not as intended. The problem arises from

```
colnames(airports) <- c("ID", "name", "city", "country", "IATA_FAA", "ICAO", "lat", "lon", "altitude", "timezone", "DST")
```

where you specify only 11 column names while there are 14 columns. For this reason, three column become named `NA`, and that is a potential problem for `merge`.

If the result (i.e., `airportD` and `airportA`) is as intended, nothing has to be changed. It is advisable to give proper column names to those three columns, though.

Comment: Ah, yes!!  That makes sense.  I made the change you recommended and now everything works fine.  I tried to resolve the issue by myself, as always, so I wouldn't have to ask a silly question, but this one eluded me.  Thanks again!!